# Can I make a shared folder in Android for multiple users?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-multiple-users

In Android 29, I want to be able to share large files between multiple Android users. Is it possible to make a shared directory that users can access? And can that directory be made browse-able by applications that the users have installed?

Or perhaps have one user with the original directory and files, and other users have a mounted/symlinked directory?

It is important for my implementation that an installed app can access this directory.

I have been navigating the Android filesystem and trying to get my head around:
`/mnt/user/0`, `/storage/emulated/0`, and `/data/media/0/` but I cannot see a way to make a symlink in another user's home directory to a folder within these directories.

Answer (score 2):

The directory that you are looking for is actually `/storage/emulated/0` in your case. I mean the only directory that could be used/accessible by all other applications is the external storage.

However, from Android Q (targetSDKVersion 29), the external storage permission has quite a few changes.

I would recommend looking into the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) of `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` if you are on an Android version that is less than Android Q.

For Android Q and greater, I would recommend looking into the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) of `getExternalFileDir`.

Also, there is a great article from @CommonsWare regarding this. Please have a look here in [his blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/03/28/death-external-storage-why.html). I am quoting from his blog here.

> For Android Q, you can add
>   `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>`
>   element in the manifest. This opts you into the legacy storage model,
>   and your existing external storage code will work.
>
> Technically, you only need this once you update your
>   `targetSdkVersion` to `29`. Apps with lower `targetSdkVersion` values
>   default to opting into legacy storage and would need
>   `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false"` to opt-out.